# vertical spacing in reledpar

Tags: formatting, reledpar

For a bilingual edition (documentclass is >book) I'm trying to hack the chapter headings of reledpar so that I can get a separate page with only the chapter number (I, II, III, etc.) and then the chapter title in the appropriate language on both pages. I'm going to ask a separate question about how to code the titles themselves so that I don't have to keep inserting them manually, but this question is just about vertical space. I've gotten the spacing to pretty much where I want it, but the coding is hideous and there HAS to be a better way to do it. But I can't figure it out and the reledpar documentation is defeating me.

Any thoughts?

[image: left page] [image: right page]

Here's as close as I could get to a MWE—it compiles but with two \lastbox errors, and I have no idea what that are or how to fix it (they don't show up in the document I'm working on and nothing I've pasted from that document seems to fix the problem)—I apologize.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}[utf8]
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    outer=0.75in,
    inner=0.875in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{I}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                    \begin{center}
                        \scshape\huge\ Left Title
                        \normalfont
                    \end{center}
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
\lettrine{L}{eft} text.
                \pend 
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                    \begin{center}
                        \scshape\huge\ Right Title
                        \normalfont
                    \end{center}
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
\lettrine{R}{ight} text.
                \pend 
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process. I tried starting off your code with `\documentclass{book}` `\usepackage{reledpar}` `\usepackage{lettrine}` `\begin{document}` and I got an error message about `\providebool` being undefined.

Comment: Whoops. I'll fix that. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Thanks—I gave as close as I could get to an MWE (a weird error I don't understand, detailed in my edit, has crept in but it doesn't seem to keep it from compiling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your multiple `\pstart` `\pend` pairings use `\vspace`. Here is a revised version of your MWE (for which thank you).

```
% reledpar.tex  SE 543766

\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}[utf8]
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    outer=0.75in,
    inner=0.875in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{comment} % for my (PW) convenience
\begin{document}
\chapter{I}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
\begin{comment}
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
\end{comment}
\vspace{1in}
                \pstart
                    \begin{center}
                        \scshape\huge\ Left Title
                        \normalfont
                    \end{center}
                \pend
\begin{comment}
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
\end{comment}
                \pstart
\vspace{0.5in}
\lettrine{L}{eft} text.
                \pend 
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
\begin{comment}
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
\end{comment}
\vspace{1in}
                \pstart
                    \begin{center}
                        \scshape\huge\ Right Title
                        \normalfont
                    \end{center}
                \pend
\begin{comment}
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
                \pstart
                \pend
\end{comment}
                \pstart
\vspace{0.5in}
\lettrine{R}{ight} text.
                \pend 
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

It also seems to compile with no `\lastbox` errors.

Comment: Oh, that works beautifully! Thank you so much! I kept trying `\vspace`—I just never tried it, you know, in the right place. :) I appreciate the help.

Comment: Be careful, verticla spacing inside \pstart \pend may cause trouble. Must time, it is better to add it inside optionnal argument of \pstart.